# Access this.props.dispatch and other action creators from component

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to use both this.props.dispatch and my own defined actions creators to dispatch actions from my react view component.

However, I can not access this.props.dispatch if I pass in mapDispatchToProps to connect(). So, this is the workaround that I came up with:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateRackGroup,
        cloneRackGroup,
        onSelectRack,
        onCloneRack,
        valRackChange,
        valRackAdd,
        onRackAction,
        valRackUpdate,
        dispatch
    }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps({
    tempRackStates,
    rackGrpsAdded,
    invalidFields
}) {
    return {
        tempRackStates,
        rackGrpsAdded,
        invalidFields
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RackgroupGenerator);
```

I am not happy with it, as "it wraps dispatch within dispatch".

So is there an elegant way to gain access to the raw dispatch method under this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass `dispatch` do `bindActionCreators`. Just merge it to the bound action creators

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    const actionCreators = bindActionCreators({
        actionCreator1,
        actionCreator2,
    }, dispatch);
    return { ...actionCreators, dispatch };
}

// or without the additional assignment
return {
    dispatch,
    ...bindActionCreators({ actionCreator1, actionCreator2 }, dispatch)
};
```

BTW I didn't test it for sure, but I also think you shouldn't "wrap dispatch with dispatch" because I believe it can lead to strange behavior such as unwillingly dispatching actions more than once.

Comment: Got it, thanks.
As long as I return my own action creators and the dispatch function in a object.